# Restore laptop to it's original OS with all data and settings kept

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, backup

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad L412 which currently has an unactivated version of Windows 7 Enterprise installed. When this laptop was bought, it had an activated version of Windows 7 Professional on it, with the serial number of it on the back of the laptop.

This means, Windows 7 Enterprise has been installed over Windows 7 Professional, and the key they used expired or was pirated.

I want to restore the laptop back to it's original factory settings without losing any documents, installed software or settings. How do I do this?

I've already seen the Windows 7 Backup utility, but this doesn't backup my settings and installed.

I also read [this thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/downgrading-from-windows-7-ultimate-to-windows-7/d0572e74-9eac-48f0-a5db-ba1c7031fb41), but i'm afraid when I install a new Windows version on my laptop, I still lose my settings and installed software.

*Note: I don't have a Windows 7 Professional installation disk*

Comment: You are going to need a copy of Win7 Pro in any case. I suppose you can try installing it over Win7 Enterprise. Is the serial number still available by the way?

Comment: @Karan The laptop also has the function to restore itself to it's factory settings, which includes the Windows 7 Professional image. Does this work? And yes, it is.

Comment: I didn't suggest factory restore since it obviously doesn't fit your requirements as stated. The Win7 Pro copy in it is unlikely to help given you don't want to lose any installed programs or settings (docs can be backed up so not a big deal).

Comment: @Karan The settings aren't backed up right? When installing from a disk?

Comment: A [repair install](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html) (i.e. installing on top of an existing copy) will retain almost all settings and apps, but in your case installing Win7 Pro over Enterprise probably will not count as one. Still, as I suggested above you can try.

Comment: @Karan Alright, and is this just the same procedure as  just normally installing Windows? Also, i'm not sure how i'm going to retrieve a Windows 7 Professional install disk....

Comment: I linked to a full repair install tutorial. Win7 copies were available via Digital River and still are available from MS directly, but unfortunately not for OEM users. Only people with retail keys can download a copy from MS whereas OEM users are told to contact the manufacturer. If you are going to attempt a 'repair' install (which in this case has a high probability of wiping everything since these are two different versions), I would advise that you hang on and give others a few days to come up with a better answer. If there are no better ideas put forth then you can go right ahead.

Comment: @Karan Thanks for the info, but to be honest, I dont want to risk it to lose/wipe data. I'd rather wait a few more days for a solution :) It's not that big of a problem so far.

Comment: "I dont want to risk it to lose/wipe data. I'd rather wait a few more days for a solution." - Isn't that just what I recommended above? :)

Comment: You are not going to be able to downgrade from Enterprise to Professional.  I am not sure why people are telling you anything except to simply format the hdd and reinstall Windows after you backup your personal data.

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah i could do that.. but I haven't found a tool yet which also backups settings and installed software. Could you provide one?

Comment: @Bas - I don't provide software recomendations.  Windows has a profile transfer tool built into it.  That would require additional hardware.  It might be easier just to reconfigure your applications.

Comment: @Ramhound Buying additional hardware isn't really an option for me, either is reconfiguring the applications. The thing is, the laptop isn't mine, its for a customer.

Comment: @Bas - I am not sure what you want.  There is no way to downgrade Windows Enterprise to WIndows Professional and keep your applications and settings.  This is a problem that your client created you have to propose the best solution possible you can't do something that isn't possible.

Comment: @Ramhound Alright, so what can I backup if i still wanted to do an install of Windows 7 Proffesional? anything but my applications and settings?

Comment: What is backed up is entirely up to you.  You can manually backup the application's settings, the applications would have to be reinstalled of course, that would even be true if you just repaired the installation even if that was possible in your client's case.